# "using namespace std;" without any #include?

Tags: c++

I tried following, it worked without problem, but in this situation, std was not defined.

```
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       ....
    }
```

Comment: Try and do std::cout, won't work

Comment: `using namespace std;` implicitly declares `std`

Comment: But only std works, replacing it with other words won't work, why?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try and do std::cout, it won't work.

`using namespace std` just defines the namespace

`#include {x}` 'includes' the code within the namespace

I.e, `std::cout` would need `#include <iostream>`. Very simple explanation but it's what is going on.

Comment: But when i try "using namespace other(anything except std)", it won't work because i didn't define "other", compiler helps it?

Comment: Simply because by default the C++ program will already have the 'std' included from the compiler

Answer (score 9):

Your code is illegal. Directive `using` can only nominate previously declared namespaces, i.e. namespaces whose names can be found by name lookup.

In this case your compiler apparently gives special treatment to name `std`. It is a compiler-specific extension, which regards `std` as an *implicitly defined* namespace. If your try a different namespace name in your code, it will most likely fail to compile.

Answer (score 2):

All `using namespace std` does is tell the compiler that, when an identifier (named variable, type, etc) appears in code, to look in the `std` namespace for candidates to match the name.

Within your `main()` function, no identifiers are being used at all (the `{}` is an empty block).   So there is no need to find matching candidates, and the result of compiling will be the same in both cases.

If you add a statement like `cout << "Hello\n"` to `main()`, then the `using namespace std` will cause the compiler to consider anything named `cout`  within namespace `std` as a valid match for the identifier `cout`.   If this comes after `#include <iostream>`, then `std::cout` is considered a viable match.   If declarations in `<iostream>` are not visible to the compiler (in your case, because there is no `#include <iostream>`) then the compiler cannot consider `std::cout` to be a candidate match for `cout`, and will issue a diagnostic accordingly.

The C++ standard does not specify anything different about `std` or about using directives that require `using namespace std` and `using namespace othername` to behave differently.   If your compiler treats them differently (recognising namespace `std` but not others, even if there is no declaration of one) then that is specific to your compiler.

Comment: Before we  "using namespace something", we need declare "something", but "std" needn't(just like the examplt), why?

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify anything different about `std` or about using directives that require `using namespace std` and `using namespace othername` to behave differently.    If your compiler treats them differently, then that is specific to your compiler.   I'll edit to include a note about that shortly.

Comment: Would "std::type_info" and "std::initializer_list<T>" be forward declared (though not necessarily complete) even without any includes?  If so, the "std" namespace would have to exist.

Comment: The compiler having visibility of a type in a header that is not included would, logically, break the philosophy of keeping "core language" and "library" separate, so I'd be surprised if the standard would require it.     A program is ill-formed if it uses `typeid` without a preceding `#include <typeinfo>`.    A brace-init-list (construct like `{a,b,c}`) is bound to `auto`, which means its type can be anonymously deduced by the compiler and suggests the compiler wouldn't need to see a declaration of `std::initializer_list` to deduce the type.

Comment: @David ["The template std​::​initializer_­list is not predefined; if the header <initializer_­list> is not included prior to a use of std​::​initializer_­list — even an implicit use in which the type is not named — the program is ill-formed."](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#2)